# Why does perl use \g1 for backreferences and everyone else uses \1?

Tags: regex, perl

I am curious about the historical reason for the divergence in syntax between Perl regex backreferences and everyone else's (C++, grep, emacs, literally every other usage I've seen).

Perl uses `\g1` for a group backreference. Everyone else uses a syntax which seems much cleaner, just `\1`.

Comment: I think it is so relative and named backreferences like `\g{-1}` and `\g{name}` are less confusing.  If you just used `\{-1}` or `\{name}` would that be more confusing?

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah, `\{` already has a meaning, so that's a no-go. Escapes sequences must match `/^\\\w/`

Comment: Re "*I am curious about the historical reason for the divergence in syntax between Perl regex backreferences and everyone else's*", If there was a divergeance, you would have to ask them cause most regex languages are based on Perl's :D

Comment: First, it's not "_everyone else_" -- for example, [python has `\g<N>`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) and [.NET has `\k{N}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions)). Anyway, they (the "_everyone else_") mostly pick(ed) up features, or really all of regex, from Perl and some are now just a little behind. Most do have `\k{name}`, as they have to since they support capturing by name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, Perl does accept `\1`.

```perl
/^(.)\1\z/s    # Equiv* to length($_) == 2 && substr($_, 0, 1) eq substr($_, 1, 1)
```

`\g` is a far more recent and far more flexible addition.

```
\1             # Matches the text captured by the nth capture
\g{1}   \g1    # Matches the text captured by the nth capture
\g{-1}  \g-1   # Matches the text captured by the nth capture before the \g
\g{name}       # Matches the text captured by (?<name>...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl v5.10 stole a bunch of stuff from other regex implementations. Perl's the magpie of languages: if something else has a bright and shiny feature, Perl tends to subsume it.

[regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good resource to compare regex flavors across languages. Here's it's page on [relative backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backrefrel.html).

At the same time, Perl also stole named captures that you can reference with `\g{some_name}` (or `\k{name}` and other forms):

```
(?P<some_name>...)   # python style
(?<some_name>...).   # same thing
```

You can see most of it in [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) to check that Perl has something.

But, if you want to look at regex flavors, C++, grep, or emacs wouldn't be the places I'd look for sophisticated regex features. There are plenty of other languages that I might list first. But then, how many of those are Perl regex clones? :)